# Where can I find information on the published topics?

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I find any documentation on the topics that are published when openni_launch is running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232691/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-published-topics?/) by [new_user64](https://answers.ros.org/users/26683/new_user64/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There might be documentation on the [http://wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/) page of the corresponding ROS package (I'm guessing that's http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch).

But even if there isn't, you can always do `rostopic list` and then `rostopic info [topic name]`, as well as `rosnode list` and `rosnode info [openni-related node name]`

---

Originally posted by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) with karma: 1788 on 2016-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1